# Dictionary of arrays of lambda-like function pre c++11

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a verilator test that is a bit complicated. I am building a cpu in verilog and I would like to make sure that control signals are correct at certain stages. As such I am trying to write some code that works as follows:

```
checkAssertion(phase=2, instruction=3766636548)
```

I was hoping to implement this as

```
std::map<int, std::function<bool()>[5]>
```

This way for every instruction I aim to test I could look up the instruction and check that the state is valid for a specific instruction at a specific phase.

I also tried making something that looked like this as well

```
std::vector<std::function<bool()>> functors;
functors.push_back([&] { return read_cpu_var("phase") == 0; });
functors.push_back([&] { return (read_cpu_var("phase") == 1) && (read_cpu_var("register_read_1") == 2); });
functors.push_back([&] { return read_cpu_var("phase") == 2; });
functors.push_back([&] { return read_cpu_var("phase") == 3; });
functors.push_back([&] { return read_cpu_var("phase") == 4; });
```

However it seems that this will not work as I cant get verilator to compile the c++ as c++11. Though if you are curious this is the build and run command

```
verilator -Wall --trace -cc --vpi cpu.v --exe  -std=c++11 ../TestBenches/cpu_verify.cpp && make -j -C obj_dir -f Vcpu.mk Vcpu && obj_dir/Vcpu
```

So without c++11 I am without lambdas and without std::function. I figured those would be an eloquent way to lay out each of the assertions for each of the phases. How would I do this eloquently before c++11

Comment: You have to declare the functions beforehand. suppose you could implement an equivalent to `std::function` in C++03, and intended to use locally-declared functors (which is basically what lambdas are). Problem is, your `std::function` would need to use a templated constructor in order to be able to accept different types (and them erase the type internally) and, in C++03, you can't use locally-declared types as template parameters.

Comment: [this is what I'm talking about](https://godbolt.org/z/dh_AnL) (Disregard the sloppy implementation of `function`). Try moving the declaration of `my_functor` to the inside of `main()`.